# how to test if there is specific object property value already stored in local storage array

Tags: javascript, html

I have two input values in my HTML, siteName and siteUrl and I am asigning them to two objects property (name:siteName, url:siteUrl). Then after object was created I am pushing it to an array and storing into browsers local storage, but before it goes to local storage I want to test object property name value and if it is already there to alert me

This is my code for now...

```
//get site name and site url
var siteName = document.getElementById('siteName').value; 
var siteUrl = document.getElementById('siteUrl').value;

var bookmark = {

  name:siteName,
  url:siteUrl
}

/test if item bookmarks is null
if(localStorage.getItem('bookmarks') === null){

//Initiate Array
var bookmarks = [];

//add to array
bookmarks.push(bookmark);

//set to local storage
localStorage.setItem('bookmarks', JSON.stringify(bookmarks));


//get bookmarks from local storage
}else{
var bookmarks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('bookmarks'));

//add bookmark in array
bookmarks.push(bookmark);


//re-set back to local storage
localStorage.setItem('bookmarks', JSON.stringify(bookmarks));

}
```

Comment: So, where did you stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to do this.

1st method-

```
//get localstorage value
var bookmarks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('bookmarks'));
var flagExists = false;

if(bookmarks != null && bookmarks.length > 0){
    for(var i=0; i<bookmarks.length; i++){
        var existingBookmark = bookmarks[i];
        //check if your current value against key name is already present in any existing bookmar 
        if(bookmark.name === existingBookmark.name){
            //do anything that you want here
            flagExists = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

2nd Method is to use [Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4) Library. With lodash you can do this in one line.

```
//get localstorage value
var bookmarks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('bookmarks'));
var flagExists = false;
var _ = require("lodash");

if(bookmarks != null && bookmarks.length > 0){
    var flagExists = _.find(bookmarks, {'name': bookmark.name}) != null;
    //do whatever you want
}
```

Comment: Cool. Anyways you should be using the 1st method for such simple task. Lodash is quite big and should be either used if you need many functions from the library or using ES6 style imports.

Comment: No problem. Can you please accept the answer if it worked for you. This will help others who stumble upon this same question.

Answer (score 0):

you can it by using .length The length property returns the number of elements in an array. And .valueOf() method return value of string object but .valueOf() you can't use explicitly in your code.